# Downloading C++ Driver for MongoDB

Tags: git, github

I feel like an absolute idiot for asking, but I'm not able to even download the C++ driver for mongoDB. I'm running a 32-bit Fedora 21 box, and it's also where the mongodb instance is running. I've been following the instructions on this [page](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/wiki/Download-and-Compile-the-Legacy-Driver).

and it tells me to perform the following cmd to clone the repository:

```
[user@host ~]$ git clone git@github.com:mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver.git
Cloning into 'mongo-cxx-driver'...
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

As you can see, it looks like the remote host is expecting a form of public key authentication. The documentation doesn't reference any other steps that need to be taken (except for installing the necessary software boost, python, git, and scons which I've done) in order to clone this repo to my local machine. Is anyone else running into this same problem? Any ideas of what to do?

Thanks as always!

Comment: Has nothing to do with programming

Comment: I'm pretty sure git and github would fall under "software tools commonly used by programmers" as defined in the Help Center

Comment: as well as notepad or IDE, but I highly doubt a lot of people would agree that questions like "I can not install notepad" should be here.

Comment: I don't think notepad vs the C++ driver for MongoDB is a completely fair comparison, but as the question's already been answered, your point is ultimately moot. This entire page can be deleted if it's to your satisfaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this command instead:

```
git clone https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver.git
```

The reason your initial command is not working is because it is attempting to pull using a secure connection method. This will only work if you have an ssh keypair locally that is linked to your github account.

The difference with this new command is it is looking at a public url that can authenticate if necessary (not in this case).

[More information](https://help.github.com/articles/which-remote-url-should-i-use/)

Comment: Thanks, figured it was something simple like that